# strtod128 function and memory leak (gcc 8.3.1)

Tags: c, linux, memory-leaks

It is assumed that a memory leak occurs when using the strtod128 function.
Has anyone experienced the same thing? I want to know how to solve this works.
(gcc version is 8.3.1 in Redhat)

Comment: Pretty sure it is not happening when using `strtod128`. And you can convince yourself (or convince us in the contrary) by constructing a minimal program using it and demonstrating the issue or the lack of it.

Comment: It's plausible. Looking at `FUNCTION_L_INTERNAL` in [strtod32.c](https://github.com/libdfp/libdfp/blob/master/stdlib/strtod32.c), `newlocale()` is called, but not all paths through the function call `freelocale()`.

Comment: I raised it as an [issue](https://github.com/libdfp/libdfp/issues/169). We'll see what happens.

Comment: **@IanAbbott**  I checked the issue you raised and your pull request. It helped me a lot. Thank you very much!